# Mobile View rendering issue while hosting on webserver

Tags: css, angularjs, html, mobile, twitter-bootstrap-3

We are not able to render responsive mobile view for website while testing on local
when same code is hosted on server,mobile view is not getting rendered.

i tried looking into view port setting,they looks correct

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

i am not able to find reason why website is not able to render mobile view.
can someone suggest me possible solution
[website url](http://gimmewings.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are opening [Website](http://gimmewings.com/) inside a iframe which is not having the viewport meta tag

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: thanks.wanted to check one more thing..is this iframe loaded automatically on webserver because same frame is not visible locally.sorry if question looks naive

Comment: I dont think so its added automatically on webserver

Comment: I think,generated due to usage of fb like button.if there is way to disable iframe..will add in answer